# When to call setsockopt? Before bind() and connect()?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, setsockopt

I inherited some TCP code that called:

```
bind(tcpSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
```

before the call to

```
setsockopt(tcpSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int));
```

Not surprisingly, this lead to the message: "Address already in use".  Simply swapping the order of the calls resolved the problem.

This brings up a question: In general, should any calls to `setsockopt()` be made before a call to `bind()`? Before a call to `connect()`?

Answer (score 11):

`SO_REUSEADDR` needs to be set before `bind()`.  However, not all options need to be set before `bind()`, or even before `connect()`.  It really depends on the specific options being set, so you have to deal with them on an option-by-option basis.