# Can I change the mask on a canbus socket after bind()?

Tags: c++, sockets, bind, can-bus, setsockopt

**I saw a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942977/when-to-call-setsockopt-before-bind-and-connect) but it didn't answer mine.**

I'm using `canbus` communication in my program with a `mask`, here is an example, taken from [can-utils](https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils/blob/master/candump.c):

```
struct can_filter {
    canid_t can_id;
    canid_t can_mask;
};

struct can_filter *rfilter;
setsockopt(s[i], SOL_CAN_RAW, CAN_RAW_FILTER, rfilter, numfilter * sizeof(struct can_filter));

/* try to switch the socket into CAN FD mode */
setsockopt(s[i], SOL_CAN_RAW, CAN_RAW_FD_FRAMES, &canfd_on, sizeof(canfd_on));

bind(s[i], (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr))
```

.
.
.

```
int ret = select(s[currmax - 1] + 1, &rdfs, NULL, NULL, timeout);
int nbytes = recvmsg(s[i], &msg, 0);
```

In this example, I set the `mask` and than `bind` so every time I will `receive` a message from the `socket`, it will be with the same `mask`.

Is it possible to change the `mask` after the `bind` and before `receive`?

Example:

```
/* try to switch the socket into CAN FD mode */
setsockopt(s[i], SOL_CAN_RAW, CAN_RAW_FD_FRAMES, &canfd_on, sizeof(canfd_on));

bind(s[i], (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr))
```

.
.
.

```
setsockopt(s[i], SOL_CAN_RAW, CAN_RAW_FILTER, rfilter, numfilter * sizeof(struct can_filter));
int ret = select(s[currmax - 1] + 1, &rdfs, NULL, NULL, timeout);
int nbytes = recvmsg(s[i], &msg, 0);
```

Comment: "*I saw a similar question but it didn't answer mine*" - because it is not even remotely close to your question. `setsockopt()` is used for a lot of different  options. Some can be set/changed after `bind()`, and some can't. You are going to have to refer to the can-bus documentation to see whether the `CAN_RAW_FILTER` option can be changed after `bind()` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @RamyLebeau for the [SocketCAN referral](https://docs.kernel.org/networking/can.html#raw-protocol-sockets-with-can-filters-sock-raw).

From the documentation:

> RAW protocol sockets with can_filters (SOCK_RAW)
>
> Using CAN_RAW sockets is extensively comparable to the commonly
> known access to CAN character devices. To meet the new possibilities
> provided by the multi user SocketCAN approach, some reasonable
> defaults are set at RAW socket binding time:
>
> - The filters are set to exactly one filter receiving everything
> - The socket only receives valid data frames (=> no error message frames)
> - The loopback of sent CAN frames is enabled (see chapter 3.2)
> - The socket does not receive its own sent frames (in loopback mode)
>
> `These default settings may be changed before or after binding the socket`

I can change the `mask` before or after `binding` the `socket` and before every `can` message `receive`.